# Create an HTML Dropdown in Layout in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dashboard and the sidenav is in the layout.cshtml.  I have a modal that contains a dropdown list that works in the home/index.  However, upon being on a different page, the modal will not trigger.  It was then I discovered, the modal needs to be in the layout so it can be fired from any page due to the link in the sidenav.

However, when I moved the modal to the layout.cshtml, I get an error

```
Line 186: @Html.DropDownList("DomainDropDownList", ViewBag.domainSelectionList as SelectList, new { @class = "select" })

[InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'DomainDropDownList'.]
```

I then realized it's because there is no ViewData since it's in the layout.cshtml.

I looked this up and came across that I could use ViewComponents, but that's in Core, I'm not using Core.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get a dropdown list in the layout.cshtml using:

```
SelectList DomainDropDownList = new SelectList(DomainManagement.ListIsDomainAlive(), "id", "domainName");
ViewBag.domainSelectionList = DomainDropDownList;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should change

`@Html.DropDownList("DomainDropDownList", ViewBag.domainSelectionList as SelectList, new { @class = "select" })`

to

`@Html.DropDownList("domainSelectionList", ViewBag.domainSelectionList as SelectList, new { @class = "select" })`

because of `ViewBag` name is `domainSelectionList` not `DomainDropDownList`